# preg_split results in connection reset

Tags: php, regex, preg-split, connection-reset

```
preg_split("/({{\s*(?:(?!}}).)+\s*}})/s", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
```

That line makes Apache reset the connection. `data.txt` is approximately 12 kB.

What am I doing wrong, can I optimize the regex somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression instead:

```
/({{(?>(?:[^}]|}[^}])+)}})/s
```

The main improvements:

- **`(?>…)`** – [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to avoid backtracking
- **`(?:[^}]|}[^}])+`** – no look-around, no non-greedy matching

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file into a variable than passing it to preg_split. I think it's file_get_contents`problem rather than`preg_split`.